# Unable to update a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

While trying to update a column row in mysql, it complains that the

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'total_amount' cannot be
>   null

Meanwhile the

> total_amount

spelling in the script correlate to the

> total_amount

in the database table.

This is the update code

```
public function updateOrder(){
        $updateOrders = 'UPDATE `orders` SET total_amount = (SELECT SUM(unit_cost * quantity) FROM `order_detail` WHERE ';
        $updateOrders .= 'id = ' . $this->key . ') WHERE id = ' . $this->key;
        $this->query($updateOrders);
        $this->cartEmpty();
        return $this->key; 
    }
```

This is the code that sanitized the input from user

```
private function query($sql, $parameters = []) {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($parameters);
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysql. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, the error message is pretty clear...you're trying to set the total_amount column to NULL when it is not allowed to be NULL. So I would check that the $updateOrders SQL looks like you're expecting before you execute it, and that the subquery returns a valid result. It's nothing to do with spellings. Have you not tried to debug this yet??

Comment: Check your `order_detail` table fields.

Comment: If `total_amount` has a `not null` constraint, then you should check if `SELECT SUM(unit_cost * quantity) FROM order_detail WHERE id = <some_id>` is not null in the first place.

Comment: It is sanitized using prepared statements. the function is inside the function $this->query()

Comment: It's sad to tell your but your query __is not sanitized__.

Comment: @u_mulder am using pdo which as I learn is already sanitized

Comment: You're doing concatenation. That means you're one mistake away from disaster. Use **prepared statements with placeholder values** whenever possible. If you inject data either through interpolation or concatenation then you might make a mistake and that mistake could be catastrophic. If you're doing manual escaping you might forget. If you use placeholders you can't forget, it won't work unless you bind properly. It fails safely, not dangerously.

Comment: @GbengaOgunbule "It is sanitized using prepared statements. the function is inside the function $this->query()" ...so what? By that time you already added the potentially dangerous values directly into the SQL string, without using parameters. A prepared statement by itself is not any protection if you don't combine it with using parameters. If you think you are safe the way you are coding it right now, then I'm sorry but you don't understand the SQL injection topic properly. Read the bobby-tables link I gave you and refresh your knowledge.

Comment: @GbengaOgunbule "am using pdo which as I learn is already sanitized" ...again this is also a false statement for similar reasons to my last comment. Using PDO does not, in itself, make your queries safe. It's 100% possible to use PDO (or any other DB library) to run unsafe queries, as you are doing right now. You have to actually employ prepared statements **and** parameters together - in the way which is very well documented online in many places - in order to remove the vulnerability to SQL injection. Again - if you think you are safe, then sadly you do not understand this topic properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE()` in the subquery, because it always returns one row:

```
UPDATE `orders`
    SET total_amount = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(unit_cost * quantity), 0)
                        FROM . . .
```

You should also learn to use parameters.

Comment: Thanks I will look at the above code. The code is sanitized already using the created function QUERY which I  use inside the UPDATEORDER function as $this->query()

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into your table definition. The field `total_amount` is probably NOT marked as NULL, so the MySQL requires the value to be provided 
OR try this

`public function updateOrder(){
        $updateOrders = 'UPDATE`orders`SET total_amount = IFNULL((SELECT SUM(unit_cost * quantity),0) FROM`order_detail`WHERE ';
        $updateOrders .= 'id = ' . $this->key . ') WHERE id = ' . $this->key;
        $this->query($updateOrders);
        $this->cartEmpty();
        return $this->key; 
    }`

Comment: Basically wrap your (SELECT SUM(unit_cost * quantity) into IFNULL((SELECT SUM(unit_cost * quantity), 0)